# Watermark format is appearing in reverse way

Tags: c#, math, geometry

As per the code am getting watermark exactly opposite to output.[image] working in this  way as shown in pic.But i had tried to get that in reverse like other triangle [image]
 help me out..i had tried alot..

```
 Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

 // Trigonometry: Tangent = Opposite / Adjacent
 double tangent = (double)newBitmap.Height / 
                  (double)newBitmap.Width;

 // convert arctangent to degrees
 double angle = Math.Atan(tangent) * (180/Math.PI);

 // a^2 = b^2 + c^2 ; a = sqrt(b^2 + c^2)
 double halfHypotenuse =(Math.Sqrt((newBitmap.Height 
                        * newBitmap.Height) +
                        (newBitmap.Width * 
                        newBitmap.Width))) / 2;

 // Horizontally and vertically aligned the string
 // This makes the placement Point the physical 
 // center of the string instead of top-left.
 StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
 stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
 stringFormat.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Center;

 g.RotateTransform((float)angle);            
 g.DrawString(waterMarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color),
              new Point((int)halfHypotenuse, 0), 
              stringFormat);
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Is rotation of g wrong? orientation of g? Or the string watermarkText?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're currently getting a string drawn TopLeft -> BottomRight and you want the string drawn BottomLeft -> TopRight? if so just add 90 degrees.

Comment: Before you can rotate you probably need to move (TranslateTransform) the origin to the center of the rotation.. (Then rotate, then move back, then draw!)

Comment: @James Barrass you are correct but u mean i can directly give angle =90 degree... suggest me where can i add ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into this a little more and it's not as simple as adding 90 degrees.

You've made it harder for yourself by drawing the string at an offset with rotated graphics, what this means is that you are still rotating around the origin, but drawing the string further away.

The net result is that if you rotate the string it disappears (it has rotated outside the bounds of the bitmap).

[image: Rotate about the wrong point]

What you need to do is rotate around the center of the string. To do that apply a Translate transform **before** rotating and then draw at the point (0,0)

```
        g.TranslateTransform(newBitmap.Width / 2, newBitmap.Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform((float)-angle);
        g.DrawString(waterMarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color),
                     new Point(0, 0),
                     stringFormat);
```

You no longer need the halfHypotenuse variable or code.

Now as you edit the angle you should see the effect clearly.

To go from TopLeft -> BottomRight to BottomLeft->TopRight, make the angle negative.

Answer (score 0):

requirement [image]        watermark should appear like this..got it..thank u friends..

```
        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        bmPhoto.SetResolution(Resolution, Resolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.Clear(Color.White);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
        new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
        new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        String watermarkText = "For office use only";
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        matrix.Translate(bmPhoto.Width / 2, bmPhoto.Height / 2);
        matrix.Rotate(-40.0f);// as per requirement we can give angle
        grPhoto.Transform = matrix;
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", 36, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0); //Adds a transparent watermark with an 100 alpha value.
        SolidBrush sbrush = new SolidBrush(color);

        grPhoto.DrawString(watermarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color),0, 0,stringFormat);
```